# Webdriver. Starting a large number of instances on virtual machine gives WinError 10061

Tags: python, webdriver, celery, selenium-chromedriver, connection-refused

I want to run many instances of Chrome (using Chromedriver) at the same time. I use Python and Celery. On the local computer everything works without problems, but on the server (Win7 and Win10) - only seven instances of Chrome are opened, the rest are crashed when it tries to run the next instance:

ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because of the target machine actively refused it

```
[2017-04-18 08:14:43,988: ERROR/MainProcess] Task bid[7fce5818-41b5-4ff5-9ae2-41913bd88f43] raised unexpected: ConnectionRefusedError(10061, 'No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it', None, 10061, None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\env\bot\lib\site-packages\celery\app\trace.py", line 240, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\env\bot\lib\site-packages\celery\app\trace.py", line 438, in _protected_call_
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\bot\app.py", line 100, in bid
    home_page.open()
  File "E:\env\bot\lib\site-packages\webium\base_page.py", line 57, in open
    self._driver.get(self.url)
  File "E:\env\bot\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 248, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "E:\env\bot\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 234, in execute
    response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
  File "E:\env\bot\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 407, in execute
    return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
  File "E:\env\bot\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 438, in _request
    self._conn.request(method, parsed_url.path, body, headers)
  File "C:\Python35-32\Lib\http\client.py", line 1106, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "C:\Python35-32\Lib\http\client.py", line 1151, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "C:\Python35-32\Lib\http\client.py", line 1102, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "C:\Python35-32\Lib\http\client.py", line 934, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\Python35-32\Lib\http\client.py", line 877, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Python35-32\Lib\http\client.py", line 849, in connect
    (self.host,self.port), self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "C:\Python35-32\Lib\socket.py", line 711, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "C:\Python35-32\Lib\socket.py", line 702, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

I don't use Selenium Grid, I run lots of instances with next parameters:

```
def set_driver():
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_extension('extension_3_0_0_14.crx')
    return webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

Has anyone met the problem? What could be the reason? How can I solve the issue?

PS Google says that there is a problem with sockets. But why everything goes fine on my local machine and there are troubles on VM?